# Comparing of dynamically created slice string with the other slice string upto limit?

Tags: javascript

Here I have two slices :-

```
 slice1=["Friday, 06-01-2018 8:00AM 11:00AM",
         "Saturday, 06-02-2018 8:00AM 11:00AM",
         "Sunday, 06-03-2018 8:00AM 11:00AM", 
         "Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM 11:00AM"]

 slice2 =["Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM",
          "Monday, 06-11-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM"]
```

Code I'm trying:-

```
  for (var i = 0; i < slice1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < slice2.length; j++) {
        if (slice1[i]== slice2[j]) {
            console.log(slice2[j]);
        }
     }
   }
```

How will I compare each `slice1` element with the each element of the `slice2` range of the every string will be at `8:00AM` the time will be change with other records because the slice a dynamically created. Is that possible to compare the slice element like that. For example `"Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM" == "Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM"`. Can anybody will help me for this. I'm using jQuery for this. Thank you.

Comment: So, are you basically asking if you can compare strings with the `==` operator? Yes, you can. You don't need `.value` at the end. jQuery is not relevant to this question, this is just how plain JavaScript works.

Comment: You don't even need to use for loops... use array filter and find...

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you tell how it will done?

Comment: Use array methods. Filter `slice1` with a function which returns true when the current value is found (array find) in `slice2`.

Comment: Your code seems to be working if you only want to compare the strings

Comment: @evolutionxbox Right, I m comparing them but like this `"Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM" == "Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM"` ***NOT*** like this  `"Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM 11:00AM" == "Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `for` loops for this

```
for(let s1 of slice1) {
  for(let s2 of slice2) {
    if(s1 === s2) {
      console.log('match found');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For each `s1` above will iterate the `slice2`

Comment: it will compare full string not like this `"Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM" == "Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM"`.

Comment: Do you need the if statement to be true even a part of the string of slice1 element is there in slice2's element?

Comment: No, it will not giving me match found :( @senal

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, there is no element in either of your arrays like this `Monday, 06-04-2018 8:00AM`. What is the expected result from `slice1` and `slice2`

Comment: yeah i Know that's why I'm asking that is it possible i'm having slice like above and i want to compare them like i says. Now tell is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171607/discussion-between-senal-and-gourav).

Comment: how will i split my array and get the values in diffrent categories

Comment: but it takes four for loops :P